# External Sharepoint Access

Tags: sharepoint-designer

We have a sharepoint site that is used by our internal staff. Now some of our outside clients want to have access to sharepoint site so they can collaborate with the group. I don’t want to give them access to the whole site because there are some company documents I don’t want to share with outside people. Is there a way to create users for certain sharepoint site? I just want clients to have access to certain site so they can share their documents. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In our company we have a similar problem. 
When a client wants access to a specific SharePoint site we generate a user account (AD) for him and grant him access to the site/page/library whatever. But there's one point. If you like to add a user to a specific site, then you have to turn off inheriting. This might could be an issue for your permission concept.

(Here's a screen on how to stop inheriting permissions)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure that your outside client can access your SharePoint site.

- Is / Are the SharePoint server(s) within your DMZ or access through a reverse proxy like ISA / Forefront, ...
- Do they access through a VPN connection ?
- How do they authenticate themselves ? AD ? FBA ?

Once authenticated and recognized within SharePoint, you can place them on specific groups (either AD groups, FBA role or native or custom SharePoint groups), brake the inheritence on the selected subsites and grand required permissions to these external groups / people.

So in short : Ensure external people can access your SharePoint site, group them (to ease the maintenance) and grant them access on selected site(s).

Comment: We access the sharepoin through a VPN but we don't want to give VPN access to our client?

Comment: If you access SharePoint through a VPN, I guess it's already hosted outside of your network, so there are good chances that it will be the same for our customers. How do you want them to connect to SP if you already need (internally) a VPN to access it ?